# Styleguidist: Failed to compile

Tags: node.js, react-styleguidist

After upgrading to latest version of react-styleguidist (7.2.3), I'm having some trouble compiling my js/jsx files.

The error I'm getting is:

```
FAIL  Failed to compile.

./src/components/Forms/Fieldset/Fieldset.jsx)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/loaders/props-loader.js):
/Users/knut.sorknes/Documents/www/test/FrontEnd/node_modules/react-styleguidist/loaders/utils/getProps.js:84
                        .reduce((prev, key) => ({ ...prev, [key]: tags[key] }), {});
                                                  ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

Anyone else having this problem?

Edit: It helps to have the right version of Node installed (8.3.0)

Comment: That's a bug! Should be fixed in the next patch release. I've also [created a ticket](https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/issues/1096) to prevent such issues in the future.